# How to Install a package from github on a server?

Tags: r, installation, package

I get the following error whenever I try to install this package on a server but I am successfully able to do so locally on my computer.

```
devtools::install_github("mobilizingcs/mobilizr", upgrade = FALSE)
```

> Error in library(mobilizr) : there is no package called ‘mobilizr’
> Calls: suppressPackageStartupMessages -> withCallingHandlers ->
> library Execution halted Error: Failed to install 'mobilizr' from
> GitHub:   (converted from warning) installation of package ‘glue’ had
> non-zero exit status

Comment: Do you have a network connectivity problem from your server to GitHub? (Firewall, etc. etc blocking access?)

Comment: have you installed devtools `install.packages("devtools")`?

Comment: `install.packages("glue")`